# Python 2.7.5: Change type 'function' to type 'int'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function that returns a number. I added this number to an integer type but it threw me an error, saying the number returned by the function was a 'function' type.

How do I convert the 'function' type to 'int' type so i can perform math functions on them? Is there a way to make the function return an 'int'?  I tried the following in the function but it still won't return an 'int' type:

```
def cost_of_trip(city, days, extra):
    return int(car_cost(days) + hotel(days) + transportation(city) + extra)

print cost_of_trip("Madrid", 7, 2500)

print type(cost_of_trip)
```

but the function still returns:

```
type 'function'
```

Comment: Post all of your code. There isn't enough info here to guess what your issue is.

Comment: Type checking is rarely needed in Python. Your function works just fine (although the first parameter is unused).

Comment: Python functions do not have a fixed return-value type. A function can return any object, and different code paths through a function might return objects of different types.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am beginning to understand now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the function object itself will always be `function` (what else could it be?), but the type of its result is an `int` (if you make it return one):

```
>>> def foo(bar):
...     return int(bar)
...
>>> type(foo)
<type 'function'>
>>> type(foo("1"))
<type 'int'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost 10 years late, but you can use classes with __add__ dunder method, i think.

```py
class Foo:
  def __init__(self,value):
    self.value=value
  def __add__(self,other):
    if type(other) is Foo:
      return Foo(other.value+self.value)
    else:
      return NotImplemented

foobar=Foo(2)+Foo(5)
print(foobar.value)
no=Foo(2)+"no" #TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Foo' and 'str'
```